# Firebase get document length inside collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am trying to get how many documents my collection has in order to setup next ID when adding a document.

I am using angularfire to connect to firebase.
I have a service to get value from firebase

asignaturas.service.ts

```
addAsignatura() {
      return this.db.collection('asignaturas').valueChanges();
   }
```

asignaturas.component.ts

```
 onSend(){
    this.dbService.addAsignatura()
    .subscribe(data => {
      return this.size = data.length;
      
      
    });
    this.size = this.size + 1;
      this.docID = this.size.toString();
    this.dbService.getCollectionAsignaturas().doc(this.docID)
      .set({codigo: 12, nombre: 'xcssdf'});
   
  }
```

I have a button in html to send this information to firebase, so am trying to subscribe to the observable and count the length, my issue is that when i click for the first time in the button, nothing happens and the count var is not update, all works ok when i click for the second time

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console or network tabs in the Chrome developer console?

Comment: The first time you click button you are firing the subscriber, in this case its probably that this.size is a null value, then when the observable ends and call subscribe this is settin a number value to this.size.   This is the reason the second time works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making an aynchronous call inside 'addAsignatura', the value of 'this.size' won't be updated until we get the result from that call. The program execution moves ahead in the meantime and executes the other statements.

In order to achieve the desired behaviour, place the remaining code inside the callback function like this :

```
    onSend(){
       this.dbService.addAsignatura()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.size = data.length;
            this.size = this.size + 1;
            this.docID = this.size.toString();
            this.dbService.getCollectionAsignaturas().doc(this.docID)
             .set({codigo: 12, nombre: 'xcssdf'});
  
       }); 
    }
```

Comment: thanks Naveen Chahar, this helped me out. 
However i noticed i had to unsubscribe then, cs it was creating me thousands of records in the database

Comment: Happy to help!! Also it is always advisable to unsubscribe in order to avoid memory leaks( although in some cases you get automatically unsubscribed on completion of request but that is not always the case).